# Netlogo while loop only one time

Tags: loops, while-loop, netlogo

I have a small problem in Netlogo, which I began to work on only a few days ago, I try to make a maze with two adventurers, and I make them go from two different starting locations, to one final location. All the beginning of my code works fine, to draw my maze, but when I want to make the adventurers go, only one of them goes in the right direction and find the exit, and the second doesn't even go in the asked direction (East).
I think the problem is in my GO procedure, but I can't reach to find a solution...
Here is my code, I work on Netlogo 5.2

```
to createaventurier
create-aventuriers pointsdepart
[set shape "person"
set color pink
set size 1 
move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = green]
ask patch-here
[set pcolor blue]
set beta ycor
]
show count aventuriers                                   
end
```

Here the program does what it's supposed to do.

```
to go
set i 0
createaventurier
while [i < pointsdepart] 
[show count aventuriers
ask one-of aventuriers
[set heading 90
  execute]
set i i + 1
]
show count pas
end
```

And it's here that the program return that there are no adventurers (no agents or agentsets) while the observer returns me that there are two of them (when I want two adventurers). I Breed-ed them at the beginning of the code, and I used a lot of while loops in other procedures, which worked perfectly. 
I'm not at ease with the software, I'm just looking for a simple explanation, (I'm not so good in english too).
If you need some other parts of my program I can post it, but I don't think they'll be needed. If you need more informations I can also post it, but I hope I have been clear enough.

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code. I have changed adventurers into turtles so I didn't need `breeds` and hard-coded the number 2 for your variable pointsdepart. It works fine, in the sense that there are always 2 turtles.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ask n-of 20 patches [set pcolor green]
  reset-ticks
end

to make-agents
  create-turtles 2
  [ set shape "person"
    set color pink
    set size 1
    move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = green]
    ask patch-here [ set pcolor blue]
  ]
  show count turtles                                   
end

to go
  let i 0
  make-agents
  while [ i < 2 ]
  [ show count turtles
    ask one-of turtles
    [ set heading 90
      forward 1
    ]
    set i i + 1
    ]
  show count turtles
end
```

This suggests that the problem is in your `execute` function (which I replaced with `forward 1`).

Running my code will demonstrate a logical problem. You are looping through (twice in this example) and running `ask one-of` in each loop. `one-of` selects a random turtle, so you might get them each to run your execute code once, or you might have the same turtle chosen each time. It is very likely you want code that looks more like this:

```
to go
  make-agents             ; note - should really be in setup, not go
  ask turtles
  [ set heading 90
    forward 1
  ]
  show count turtles
end
```

Also, you would generally have a `tick` command at the end of the `go` procedure to advance the clock and then the `go` procedure is run again so the turtles continue to move etc. This is why I have commented that the call to create the adventurers should really be in the `setup` procedure, otherwise another 2 adventurers will be created each time the clock advances.

The setup procedure is for everything that needs to be in place for the beginning of the simulation (eg creating adventurers, setting up your maze, giving initial resources to adventurers). The go procedure is for the actual process that is being simulated (eg moving, obtaining resources from the environment, depleting energy).

Comment: I solved my problem, in fact when I called the second or any other adventurer I wasn't specific enough, I just specified with a color which adventurer to use for the procedure and it was OK. At the beginning they are all yellow, the first one turns pink and execute the procedure and die. The next one turns pink and execute the procedure and die, and so on for the others. Thank you for your help.